# Append release and platform strings to MSI output in Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a Visual Studio 2010 setup project that produces MSI file.
The name of the output file can be specified (right click -> Properties -> Output file name:)

Is there a way to automatically append packaging assembly version and platform to the name?
Something like "MyProduct-{AssemblyVersion}-{Platform}.msi"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the MSI in a postbuild event but do realize that changing the MSI name will force a Major Upgrade.

Comment: What do you mean by "..changing the MSI name will force a Major Upgrade." If I have "DetectNewerInstalledVersion=True" and "RemovePreviousVersions=True" properties set won't that take care of upgrades even if the MSI file names were different?

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot that VDPROJ only supports major upgrades in the first place.